# Pandas vectorized computation with boolean operation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Consider the following code snippet:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> A = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[8,9]])
>>> A["result"] = A[0] % 2 == 0
>>> A
   0  1  result
0  1  2   False
1  3  4   False
2  8  9    True
```

So far this is ok. But if I want to do the following, it gives me an error:

```
>>> A["result"] = (A[0] % 2 == 0) and (A[1] % 2 == 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/space/env/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 953, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

It seems that, when it comes to vectorized operation in DataFrame, we can not do two operations in one assignment. I'm wondering is there a way to achieve this without
1. manually iterating over the whole dataframe
2. creating two additional columns to store the intermediate value

Comment: Use `&` not `and` for vectorized conjunction

Comment: `A["result"] = (A[0] % 2 == 0) & (A[1] % 2 == 1)`